# Calculate # of Rowspans and Colspans based on keys in a Multi-Array

Tags: php, html, css, tablelayout

I have these 2 types of layouts, basically, it can be any layout really.  I have decided to use tables for this, since using div tags cause undesirable results in some possible layout types.

Here are 2 pics that describe the returned results of row and column:

[alt text http://acs.graphicsmayhem.com/images/SimpleLayout.png](http://acs.graphicsmayhem.com/images/SimpleLayout.png)

This would return the $layout array like so:

```
$layout[0][0]
$layout[0][1]
$layout[1][1]
```

In this layout type: `$layout[1][0]` is NOT SET, or doesn't exist.  Row 1, Column 0 doesn't exist in here.  So how can we use this to help us determine the rowspans...?

[alt text http://acs.graphicsmayhem.com/images/MoreComplexLayout.png](http://acs.graphicsmayhem.com/images/MoreComplexLayout.png)

Ok, this layout type would now return the following:

```
$layout[0][0]
$layout[0][1]
$layout[1][0]
$layout[2][0]
$layout[2][1]
$layout[3][1]
```

Again, there are some that are NOT SET in here:

```
$layout[1][1]
$layout[3][0]
```

Ok, I have an array called $layout that does a foreach on the row and column, but it doesn't grab the rows and columns that are NOT SET.  So I created a for loop (with the correct counts of how many rows there are and how many columns there are).  Here's what I got so far:

```
// $not_set = array();
for($x = 0; $x < $cols; $x++)
{
    $f = 0;
    for($p = 0; $p < $rows; $p++)
    {
        // $f = count($layout[$p]); 
        if(!isset($layout[$p][$x]))
        {
            $f++;
            // It could be a rowspan or a Colspan...
            // We need to figure out which 1 it is!

            /*
            $not_set[] = array(
                'row' => $p,
                'column' => $x,
            );
            */
        }

        // if ($rows - count($layout[$p]))

    }
}
```

Ok, the $layout array has 2 keys.  The first 1 is [ row ] and the 2nd key is [ column ].
Now looping through them all and determining whether it's NOT SET, tells me that either a rowspan or a colspan needs to be put into something somewhere.  I'm completely lost here.

Basically, I would like to have an array returned here, something like this:

```
$spans['row'][ row # ][ column # ] = Number of rowspans for that <td> element.
$spans['column'][ row # ][ column # ] = Number of colspans for that <td> element.
```

It's either going to need a colspan or a rowspan, it will definitely never need both for the same `<td>` element.  Also, the pics above show for only 2 columns, there can be more than 2 columns.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If a div causes *undesirable results* you are likely doing something wrong. Tables are not for layout. It's semantically incorrect and imposes a number of accessibility problems. Consider using a CSS framework. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_framework and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design

Comment: Well, there is a bit of a problem with divs when you have more than 3 columns.  For example, I may want 5 columns, 1 div on each side, but for the 3 middle columns, I want them to be on the inside, correctly aligned.  And I want each div on each side to span like 5 rows, there are 5 rows of divs on the inside, and yet I need those 3 divs on each of the 5 rows (in the middle) to fully expand to the width so that each div is equal in width to each other.  And this has to work in all browsers.

So, this isn't working with divs, sorry.

Comment: And actually, the problem exists for 3 divs.  Let's say I want 1 div on each side, you can do a float: right, float: left, and than do a margin left and right to contain the middle div in the middle to make it span the whole middle area, but now, what if I want 2 divs in the middle area, and I want these divs to fully expand side by side to the width of the middle.  I have tried this for days to get 2 divs side by side in the middle <div> and fully expand the divs to be contained in the middle div area, and it just won't work! Unless you can offer a solution that would work....

Comment: I agree with Gordon, use a CSS framework, it will do what you want it to do.

Comment: This is a project that will let the end-user choose as many columns/rows that they want.  The builder.yaml.de link you supplied only allows up to 3 columns.  So this won't work.  I'm not sure adding a bunch of CSS Frameworks is the answer, as you can see I almost got it all figured out with the TABLE LAYOUT above, just need a bit of help please??  This is more layout friendly without adding a bunch of css rules and stuff that is really unnecessary and just adds to the total package size.

Thank You, but you really haven't helped me at all... :(

Comment: Suppose you have a 2 x 2 grid, and your array contains [0, 0] and [1, 1]. What would the correct table output be?

Comment: @Gordon - CSS lacks in more ways than 1 when it comes to HTML tables.  Why we need to worry about so much stuff when we just want divs to naturally load up side by side.  Tables handle this so much better and many more things.

@Alohci - That would never happen.  Because, if there is a 1, 1 than there must me a 0, 1 also.  Each row/column starts out at 0. And it all begins at 0, 0. I just realized, that I am going about this the wrong way, the best way would be to separate columns and rows into their own array and than do a for loop on each, this should give me the colspans and rowspans.

Comment: @Alohci - Let me give you another example, that could work with 0, 0 and 1, 1.  If you add 1, 0 than that would mean that row 0 (first row) has a colspan="2" or if you add 0, 1 in that case 0,0 would have a rowspan="2" and the other <td> elements would not have any colspan or rowspan.  If you add both 0, 1 and 1, 0, than that would mean that no <td> elements get any rowspan or colspan.

Comment: Also, there is always going to be a [0, 0] that is a given!

Comment: You are misusing HTML for visuals. HTML is for structure. CSS is for visuals.  
@Gordon - Bytheway, I am using HTML for Structure not visuals!  I don't need visuals, I need to structure the page according to the way the end user wants it structured.  All kinds of content can reside in these <td> elements that I'm sure could have CSS.

Comment: Well what it's used for and what it's best for are 2 different things IMO.  So I prefer using the best approach.

Cheers :)

Comment: Well I guess I'm not going to get any help on this.  Thanks anyways :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the colspan & rowspan datum in the original array, rather than trying to derive them? Something like this:

```
$layout[0][0][1][1]
$layout[0][1][1][1]
$layout[1][0][2][1]
$layout[2][0][1][2]
$layout[2][1][1][1]
$layout[3][1][1][1]
```

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your response :)  The array keys for $layout go far beyond just the 2 key values.  The 3rd Key in this array links to an id value for what content goes inside of this row and column.  The $layout array is being populated with row and column values from the database, which get set when the user changes the layout.  Are you saying I need to more columns in this table, called rowspan and colspan??

Comment: Also, I know this is possible to do with just row and column, perhaps using array_keys somehow, or array_intersect_key?  I have all of the info (total row count, total column count, # of columns per row, # of rows per column, etc. etc.).  Why can't I use this info to get what I need??  Seems reasonable right?

Comment: Reasonble?  Yes.

On the contrary, though, doesn't it also seem reasonable that if, at the point at which the user creates/edits the layout the arrangement of cells is established, that would be the point to capture and store that information.  Otherwise you are building your layout twice.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point.  Good Point.  Am thinking of a way to implement this into the database now.  Perhaps I can turn the row and column columns into type string and do something like this:  column = 0:2, row = 0:0.  This would mean that position 0, 0 gets 2 colspans.  Though I really don't like dealing with strings in the database unless it's absolutely needed.  Though I suppose in this case it is.

Comment: Maybe you can give me an example of how to use the approach you provided above??
How do I get the # of rowspans/colspans from both keys for each row/column?

Comment: Thanks, but this approach is no good.  Isn't there anyone around that's good at math?